# Ленивый просмотр вперёд

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка:

```
<b><a param1="param" param2="param">link</a></b><span class="classname1">text</span><span class="classname2"></span></div>
```

Нужно найти **link** и **text**

Использую выражение:

```
<b><a[^>]*>(.*)</a></b>[^>]*>(.*)</span>
```

Но остановка происходит на конечном `</span>`. Как остановиться на самом же первом? Сделать `([^<]*)` нельзя, т.к. в text могут быть эти символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте, так:

```
<b><a[^>]*>(.*?)</a></b>[^>]*>(.*?)</span>
```

Comment: увы, что так, что так, те же яйца :(

Comment: в каком языке программирования вы используете эту регулярку?

Comment: вообще, собираюсь в PHP, но дебаг делаю тут: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Всё работает, СОТРИТЕ ВСЮ СТРОКУ с регуляркой в вашем тестере и вставьте ту, что я привел.

Comment: Вот, спасибо огромное)